# Run shiny document with table of content

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

When I add the following lines to add table of content to a shiny document:

```
toc: true
toc_float: true
```

The document fails to run. It runs fine without them. I get the following error:

`Error Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 5, column 8` (line 5 is `toc: true`)

How can I resolve this issue?

The code I ran:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---

### section 1
```{r, echo=FALSE}
sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50)

renderText({paste0(rep('blah', 100), collapse = '\n')})
```

### section 2
```{r, echo=FALSE}
renderPlot({hist(rnorm(500)[seq_len(input$slider)])})
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just missing a : from `html_document`. It should be `html_document:`

```
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
---
```